# What is visible online on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I want to make sure that my public GitHub repo (online) only contains the intended files. Am I correct in assuming that the files I can see online at `https://github.com/my-user-name/my-repo-name` (including their history) are the *only* files available to others? I.e. that there are no "hidden files" online or when a repo is cloned. Just wanted to be sure...

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, those are the only files available to others.  I don't see any reason other files would be added.

Comment: If the repository is available to some circle (public repos are open to everyone) anyone in the circle can clone it, investigate and find any sensitive information you've committed.

Comment: @phd I know that everybody can see committed files; this is not my question.

Comment: Everything that can be cloned is also visible through the web interface. No hidden files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, because you haven't given any clues as to what kind of "hidden files" you think might be included, and have so far said everybody's guesses about what you meant are wrong.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if is off topic  (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each hosting provider can set up whatever access controls they like.

In the case of GitHub specifically, if the repository is public, *everyone* has access to *every commit* in that repository, by hash ID.  From there, they can get to *every file* (because a repository contains commits and commits contain files).

If some sensitive data were committed in the past and the repository is public, you should assume they have escaped.  See also https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-close-the-stable-door-after-the-horse-has-bolted.

**Edit**: consider an example.  We create a Git repository:

```
$ cd tmp
$ mkdir sensitive
$ cd sensitive
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo secret data, no one should ever know > secret
$ echo example > README
$ git add . && git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 1211ea7] initial
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 secret
$ git rm secret
rm 'secret'
$ git commit -m "remove secret data, but it's still there"
[master de6528b] remove secret data, but it's still there
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 secret
$ ls
README
```

If we push this repository somewhere (to GitHub) and someone casually browses the result, they see only the `README` file.  But cloning the repository, or looking at the parent commit of the one *visible* commit, suddenly they have access to the secret data in a file named `secret`, just by checking out the *previous* commit.

There are no files that you *can't* find: the repository consists of its two databases, and cloning the repository copies all (usually) of the main object database and some (usually—`git clone --mirror` copies all) of the secondary names-to-hash-IDs database.  It's then possible, with maintenance commands, to browse through all the so-called *blob* objects that contain all the file data.  It's possible to find every commit object in the object database and inspect the source tree attached to each commit.

The key idea here is this: A file's presence, or absence, in the *tip* commit of any given branch, as found by turning the branch name into a hash ID and using the hash ID to extract the given commit, says nothing about any file's presence or absence in any *other* commit.  Each commit's snapshot is completely independent of all other snapshots.  Your question talks about *files you can see* (which would be those in tip commits) but then says:

> ... and their history ...

and *files* do not have history.  Commits *are* history.  The history in the example repository above consists of two commits.  The second commit has one file in it.  The first commit has two files.  One of those two files—the one named `README`—is identical in each commit, but that's simply a matter of the process I used to *make* the two commits.  Except for the fact that we will all find the initial commit by starting with the second (i.e., last) commit and working backwards, the two commits are independent.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I undertand that everybody has access to every file in every commit in a public repo. My question was about whether there are publicly accessible files in a repo that are not visible at https://github.com/my-user-name/my-repo-name (including all the history that can be browsed there).

Comment: Unless you create "files" (blob objects) and tag them, only those files that are in the commits are there. At the lowest level, a repository consists of two databases. One holds "objects": commits, trees (file name-components and modes), blobs (file content), and annotated tags (tags with extra data). The blob objects hold file contents and exist because they're found through tree objects that are found through commits. The other database holds hash IDs, indexed by names: `refs/heads/*` names are the branch names, `refs/tags/*` names are the tag names, etc.

Comment: So, cloning a repository consists of copying the main database, and copying and adjusting the name-to-hash-ID database as they are the way to get started (by hash ID) *in* the main database. The branch names in the GitHub repo become remote-tracking names in your clone; your Git creates your own branch names; your Git will in general copy their tag names, although the details are tricky; and most other names get discarded by default.

Comment: History, however, is not by *file*. History exists because commits exist, and commits link to previous commits. So if the latest commits on all the named branches have just one `README` file, the remaining commits could have many other files, yet you wouldn't see them on a casual browse.